# Securing webservice endpoints without user authentication

Tags: web-services, rest, security, mobile

My scenarios is simple and perhaps not only me deal with. I have an webservice that is used my a number of my mobile apps. I would like my webservice only be accessed from my mobile apps but I don't wish my apps's user be bothered with registering an account. How can I achieve that kinds of security?

I have read about API KEY and OTP, but it doesn't really convince me.

Comment: This is not possible, you cannot restrict an API to specific a client application only. If you describe your requirements with more detail an answer to how to achieve them may be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do what you want 100%.  The reason is that if the security is in your Mobile App, or travels over the internet, it is theoretically possible for someone to read your code or scan your traffic and then impersonate your Mobile App.

However, you can get good results with simple server side checks.  EG, from your Mobile App, add a variable into HTTP calls which is checked by your backend. And, most importantly, use SSL.  You can make this more complex as well, such as providing a token from the server and then requiring this token back on every call.

It's not unbreakable... but it will deter the casual hacker.  And it will probably only take you 10 minutes to implement.